# how to compute the integral $\int_0^1 (1-x^p)^n dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

For constants $n$ and $p$, how to compute the integral
$\int_0^1 (1-x^p)^n dx$ ?

I saw a solution using hypergeometric function and another using incomplete beta function here:
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-x^p%29^n+dx](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281-x%5Ep%29%5En%20dx)

However, I can't find the steps to approach this problem and also unable to compute the definite integrals from 0 to 1.

Comment: You can just use binomial expansion and integrate term by term.

Comment: The change of variable $t=x^p$ yields directly the (quite complete) Beta function $$\tfrac1p\cdot\mathrm{Beta}\left(n+1,\tfrac1p\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding Did's comment,
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^p)^n\,dx = \frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{1}z^{\frac{1}{p}-1}(1-z)^n\,dz = \frac{1}{p}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma\left(n+1+\frac{1}{p}\right)}\tag{1}$$
and by using the identity $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$ multiple times we get:

> $$ I = \frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(k+\frac{1}{p}\right)}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{pk}\right)^{-1}.\tag{2}$$

We may also achieve the same result by substituting $z=x^p$ then applying integration by parts multiple times. Just to be clear, I am assuming $p>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. By the symmetry of the RHS of $(1)$ we also have:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}(1-x^p)^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x^{1/n})^{1/p}\,dx. \tag{3}$$

Comment: thanks for that sweet answer. I just wanted to know, when you make the assumption, $p>0$ and $n \in N $\ {0}, in which step do make those assumptions?

Comment: @saikat: $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ is needed to write the RHS of $(2)$ as such, while $p>0$ grants that the integral in the middle term of $(1)$ is converging.

Comment: As a continuation, if we have the integral limits changed to [0,$\infty$], i.e., $\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-x^p)^ndx$, then how does the definite integral change?

Comment: @saikat: the integral is diverging if the integration range is extended to $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Does that mean that it would go to $\infty$ for any value of $n$ and $p$?

Comment: @saikat: assuming $p>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, yes.

Comment: got it. Just one last question. How do you derive:
$\frac{1}{p}\int_{0}^{1}z^{\frac{1}{p}-1}{(1-z)}^ndz = \frac{1}{p}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{p})\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1+\frac{1}{p})}$ ?

Comment: @saikat: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function